# Content script not getting executed for URL that has a hashtag (and no www)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, hashtag, content-script

This problem seems to have been sort of resolved, as long as the URL of the page you're injecting your javascript into starts with `www`. What do you do if it doesn't? Here's the relevant part of my manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "matches": ["https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!newtopic/opencomments-site-discussions"],
  "js": ["postMsg.js"]
  }
],
```

The problem, according to another stackoverflow post, is because the URL of the page doesn't begin with 'www'. Does that mean that you can't inject javascript into secure pages whose URL doesn't begin with 'www', or is there another way? This had never been a problem in the past, because my extension had run with Version 1 manifests.

Forgot to add the content script:

```
var subject = document.getElementById("p-s-0");

subject.setAttribute("value", "foo");
```

The element with ID "p-s-0" is the Subject field in the Google Groups Post page, so the field should display "foo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. That is a not valid [match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) because they only specify up to the URL *path* (the part before the `?`).

   Change the `matches` to:

   ```
   "matches": ["https://groups.google.com/forum/*"],
   ```
2. The overall URL (`https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!newtopic/opencomments-site-discussions`) is not practical because Google changes the URL parameters willy nilly.  For example, `fromgroups` is not often present, and may not have the `=` if it is.  Additional parameters, like `hl=en` come and go. (This is the reason why my earlier answer worked for me, but not for you.)

   So, using `include_globs` in the manifest would be a messy, error-prone exercise.
   The solution is to check`location.hash` within the content script.
3. The script is set to `"run_at": "document_start"`, so the content script is running before there is any node with id `p-s-0`.

   Change the manifest to `"run_at": "document_end"`.
4. The new Google groups is heavily AJAX driven. So, The "New Topic" page is usually "loaded" without actually loading a whole new page.  This means the content script will not rerun.  It needs to monitor for "new" AJAX-loaded pages.

   Check for "new" pages by monitoring [the `hashchange` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-hashchange).
5. Additionally, the `p-s-0` element is added by AJAX, and is not immediately available on a "new" page. Check for this element within a `setInterval`.

---

Putting it all together,
The **manifest.json** becomes:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "run_at":           "document_end",
        "js":               [ "postMsg.js" ],
        "matches":          [ "https://groups.google.com/forum/*" ]
    } ],
    "description":  "Fills in subject when posting a new topic in select google groups",
    "name":         "Google groups, Topic-subject filler",
    "version":      "1"
}
```

The **content script**(postMsg.js) becomes:

```js
fireOnNewTopic ();  // Initial run on cold start or full reload.

window.addEventListener ("hashchange", fireOnNewTopic,  false);

function fireOnNewTopic () {
    /*-- For the pages we want, location.hash will contain values
        like: "#!newtopic/{group title}"
    */
    if (location.hash) {
        var locHashParts    = location.hash.split ('/');
        if (locHashParts.length > 1  &&  locHashParts[0] == '#!newtopic') {
            var subjectStr  = '';
            switch (locHashParts[1]) {
                case 'opencomments-site-discussions':
                    subjectStr  = 'Site discussion truth';
                    break;
                case 'greasemonkey-users':
                    subjectStr  = 'GM wisdom';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (subjectStr) {
                runPayloadCode (subjectStr);
            }
        }
    }
}

function runPayloadCode (subjectStr) {
    var targetID        = 'p-s-0'
    var failsafeCount   = 0;
    var subjectInpTimer = setInterval ( function() {
            var subject = document.getElementById (targetID);
            if (subject) {
                clearInterval (subjectInpTimer);
                subject.setAttribute ("value", subjectStr);
            }
            else {
                failsafeCount++;
                //console.log ("failsafeCount: ", failsafeCount);
                if (failsafeCount > 300) {
                    clearInterval (subjectInpTimer);
                    alert ('Node id ' + targetID + ' not found!');
                }
            }
        },
        200
    );
}
```

Comment: The match pattern looks good, but the globs seems not sufficiently flexible. I suggest to define a function which checks the hash and does the corresponding job. Then, bind this function to a hashchange event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Brock, but the script still doesn't get executed. I don't know if the element is added by AJAX; the page gets displayed when the "New topic" button in a Google Groups page is pressed.

Comment: I did and the alert doesn't get displayed.

Comment: I don't understand why the code has to be changed so much. Like I said earlier, it used to work under version 1 of the manifest and with the classic Google Groups.

Comment: Classic Google groups operates markedly differently from the new version.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate all the work you've done, Brock, but I'm still stuck. Even with your code (after adding it, I changed "location.hash" to "#!newtopic/opencomments-site-discussions" everywhere), the content script still fails to execute (I know this because after putting a debugger; statement at the top and reloading the changes, the debugger never gets hit).

Comment: BTW, what's the 200 for near the bottom of runPayloadCode()?

Comment: What? No! Use the code exactly as-is and verify that it works (it does, I tested it). The only things you would change, **after verifying that it works as-is,**  is the stuff inside the `switch` code block. ... The 200 is the time parameter passed to `setInterval()`.  It's 200 milliseconds, meaning the code checks 5 times per second -- which is plenty fast without sucking up too many resources.

Comment: Should I keep "location.hash" and not change it to "#!newtopic/opencomments-site-discussions"?

Comment: OK, just for fun, I created a new extension consisting of just the above manifest and postMsg.js files, as is, and installed it into the browser. I refreshed a page, but nothing happened.

Comment: My mistake. After I reloaded the group page and pressed the "New topic" button, I did see the subject get updated. Thanks a million for your help, Brock.

Comment: You're welcome.  I see how one of the code's comments might be misleading. Changed it.

Comment: Well, I replaced the code in the switch statement with what my extension needs and it broke the code. I'll post another question.